# How I can write this method in Objective-C - (application: continue userActivity: restorationHandler:)?

Tags: swift, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I am implementing Universal links in my Objective-C app.

Please, help me to translate this Swift method into Objective-C:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a built-in method, which is documented both in [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application) and [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application?language=objc). The Obj-C function signature is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity 
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *restorableObjects))restorationHandler;
```

Comment: thank you, @dávid-pásztor.  It solved my problem

Comment: @Philalex Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).